# Find and replace

Tags: ruby

I have a text file that contains file paths as follows:

```
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/labe...
```

I want to replace the string "drug" by "med" wherever it occurs.

I used something like the following:

```
gsub!(/(drug)/,'medication') if contents.include? 'drug'
```

(/(drug)/ is supposed to be a regular expression, but, I may be writing
it wrongly.

Do you know what I can do to perform such task?

Comment: Is that your full program?  What exact command did you type to run it, and what effect did it have?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `content.gsub /drug/, 'medication'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are converting your text file to a string:

```
contents.gsub!(/drug/, 'medication')
```

will do the trick. No need for `if contents.include?`

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet works correctly (although--as @Ryan Rebo points out--the `if` statement modifier isn't needed).

One note: by wrapping the string "drug" in parenthesis, that creates a capture group.  The replaced string is placed into a global variable.

```
str = "drug"
str.gsub!(/(drug)/,'medication')
puts str #=> medication
puts $1  #=> drug
```